# How to use SPWM with reference voltage waveforms

Tags: pwm, induction-motor, simulink

I'm doing a simulation for an IM drive in MATLAB/Simulink and Plecs(Blockset). My model is a closed loop system and I generate the reference voltage to be applied across the motor. Now I need to generate these voltages by switching the inverter with PWM scheme but simply scaling the ref. voltage and comparing it to a triangular waveform is not working for me. Any ideas on how I can generate the switching pulses?